# Deploying App on heroku node command not found

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have basically modified this app

https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started.git

Now am trying to deploy in Heroku

My Procfile has this line

```
web:node index.js
```

And when I run this command locally,there are no probs..

However if I try to open the link in my browser after following all the steps in https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-deploy-node-js-heroku-docker/

I get an error
On checking the logs using heroku logs command I am getting 'node command not found'
Anyone knows the prob?

P.S : I tried changing Procfile contents to npm start but that doesnt launch index.js in the browser.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that you have not set the buildpacks. Buildpacks tells heroku  which kind of application is yours.

Use the below command to set the application of type nodejs.

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
```

And make sure that you have a package.json file in the root of the project which is read by heroku to install the project dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try this below in your Procfile.In my case it runs nicely.

```
 web npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add nodejs buildpack on heroku settings app,
after that you will be able to use npm commands.